# Customize permissions for each user

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, permissions, item, extranet

I'm creating an extranet for customers and on the homepage, there are multiple lists.

I was wondering when a particular user logs in, is it possible to have different items in lists show and others hidden.

**For example,**

- User A logs in. On their homepage, the lists have items A, B and C.
- User B logs in and their lists have items X, Y and Z, but they cannot see A, B or C.

Would I be able to do this, or do I have to create a different site for each user and just make new lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your description, based on my understanding, it's a List Item Permission request!

In the list, You  have two options to manage the List Item permissions as the following:

1. Set `Item-level Permissions` in Advanced Setting.

   - Go to List Setting > Advanced Setting > set `Item-level Permissions` to
   - Read items that were created by the user.
   - Create items and edit items that were created by the user

[image]

In this case, the User A can only read and edit items that created by himself

2. Manage Permission for each List Item.

   - You can create a group for the users whose should see the List item, then assign the permission for the list item by stoping the inheritance permission, then add your group that should see this list item

[image]

> **Note:** This solution is not preferred for a large number of list items.

---

**Do I have to create a different site for each user and just make new lists?**

This will depend on your current business requirements, but I suggest if the list items are not related, it's preferred to use the same site and create a new list for each audience! no need to create a different site for each user!